# control menu in activity

Tags: android, menu

I have a menu I created which I show at a button click action:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_take"
    android:title="@string/take_photo" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_gallery"
    android:title="@string/gallery" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_remove"
    android:title="@string/photo" />
```

I am trying to achieve when the menu inflates I would like for the current activity UI elements to be disabled, meaning i can only click on the menu option, and any click outside the menu will close the menu,
how can I achieve that?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should Use `Dialog` or `BottomSheetDialog` For That.